# Adding Existing Project as Azure Webjob "unable to find version 1.0.12 of package Microsoft.Web.WEbJobs.Publish when adding as webjob to web app"

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a web application(azure webapp) with Azure Continuous Delivery enabled. 
Which means that any time I make a commit and push it to the remote, it automatically builds the application and deploys it.

I also have some webjobs and I would like the process to also publish the web jobs along with web application.

I found an option in Visual Studio to attach existing project as webjob to the web application. (Right-click on Web application> Add> "Add Existing Project as Azure Webjob".

When I use the option to add a project as webjob I get an error message saying

> Unable to find version 1.0.12 of package Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish

[image]

The current latest publish package version installed in my project:

> Microsoft.Web.WEbJobs.Publish 1.1.0

The idea is that I don't want to keep publishing the webjobs separately. I would like the build and deploy process to update also webjobs at the same time.

Has anyone the same issue?

Comment: What version of VS is that with?

Comment: Vs2015  @DavidEbbo

Comment: Try 2017 if you can, but I'll ask VS experts why it may be doing that in 2015.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, Unfortunately, I wont be able to easily test it as I have no vs2017 installed on the machine.

Comment: @akd what does Help/About say about the versions you have installed? The package you mentioned ships as part of Azure App Services & Tools in VS2015 and 1.1.0 is the latest version that was shipped

Comment: @JacquesEloff I have the latest version of VS2015 Update 3 Professional.Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.50225.1. If I remove the the Webjob package from the project it tries to install version 1.0.12 of WEbJob.Publish. And when I use nuget to update packages it gets updated to latest version which is 1.1.0 then if I try to add webjob into project I get the error message as in the question.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of Help/About so we can look at the versions? The item in question is not Azure Tools, but Azure App Services & Tools. It's part of the Azure SDK, but also shipped in VS Update. That's the component we need to identify

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: not yet @bit. But check the csproj files as Tom Sun suggests. I had multiple entries (no idea why). randomly I keep getting the error. hopefully they will sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro this issue on my side with VS2015 update3. But according to the error info, I recomment you to add the following code in your `porjectName.csproj` file and run VS with administrator rights.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue as OP and already had this line in my project, and am already running as admin.